# Useful comment removed -- because of bit.ly?

Tags: support, comments

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411610/coffeescript-javascript-why-do-the-objects-in-a-cloned-array-seem-to-lose-the), the OP presents code that he says shows the value `undefined`. Looking at the code, I couldn't imagine why that would be, so I created an MCVE for him. When it didn't demonstrate what he said it did, I linked to the MCVE in a comment (since it wasn't an answer) and said (in response to "Why do these disappear") "They don't"

This comment was removed, presumably someone flagged it in some way.

Why? The comment wasn't offensive, and it *was* helpful. It demonstrated that the OP's code did not behave as they described. Nine times out of 10 in this situation, the OP sees that and deletes the question, having gotten a useful response (but not one that's worth keeping on the site).

Was it that the link was through bit.ly? It had to be, the MCVE link was too long for a comment otherwise.

Comment: After your second comment, it's very clear that it *helped* OP. I'm curious to know why the first one was removed.

Comment: He just posted a very interesting comment saying that when he first followed it, it just took him to the coffeescript front page (not to the MCVE). But that the repost worked. As it was the same link, some weird glitch must have occurred. I suspect (only suspect) he flagged the comment as unconstructive and the combination of it being really short and linking through bit.ly were enough for an overworked mod to agree. I should have posted a longer comment to start with, e.g. "I took the above and added a line to run it, and I don't see the `undefineds`: (link)" I'll do better next time.

Comment: Time for a request post of "SO-sanctioned URL sortlinker"

Comment: @meneldal It would be more constructive to just change the rules for maximum comment length to not include the length of linked URLs in the calculations.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Most likely, yes. The problem with shortlinks is that they're often used not to work around the character limit, because URLs very rarely ever get that long, but to work around the blacklist to link to sites like LMGTFY, or worse, spam.

Your original comment that was deleted looked like this:

> [They don't](http://bit.ly/1FK1NRB)

Taken out of context, this reads like a shortlink for the sake of a shortlink. The comment *itself* provides no context whatsoever, since it's just a two-word sentence. Now, I personally trust that you wouldn't stoop to such levels as linking to LMGTFY, but I can see how others might not be as trusting of bit.ly links in comments regardless of who is posting them, as well as finding a two-word sentence comment not entirely constructive.

It's unfortunate in this case that the URL you were linking to was way over the character limit. Since shortlinks are highly frowned upon on the site, if you have a very good reason to use one, it would be immensely helpful to other readers to explain your reason. Keep in mind though that some users will lie about the nature of a shortlink to trick readers into clicking them, so such comments still run a relatively large risk of being deleted. For example, it's not entirely uncommon for comments like

> Here you will find the best resource: bit.ly/...

to send you to LMGTFY.

Comment: *"if you have a very good reason to use one, it would be immensely helpful to other readers to explain your reason"* Yeah, big time. And the comment could have been clearer about^H^H^H^H^H^H^H could have said what I was linking to, too, which would have helped the OP when [some glitch occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411610/coffeescript-javascript-why-do-the-objects-in-a-cloned-array-seem-to-lose-the#comment48910258_30411610) and he didn't see the MCVE at all when following it at first.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: here's [one good reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/137096) of why one have to use url shorteners or split a comment into multiple physical comments that is cumbersome.

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't see why "*Taken out of context, this reads like a shortlink for the sake of a shortlink*" is applicable because the context is clear from the preceding comments, as it links to coffeescript.org. Or do you mean to say that the short comment would have been flagged and removed **even if** it had used the original link instead of the shortened link?

Comment: @Pacerier: The context was not immediately available at the time the flag was evaluated and even if it was, we still have no way of verifying that the link is legitimate without actually following the link.

Comment: I agree that a comment needs to provide more context.  However, "this could be abused therefore no one may use it," is poor reasoning.