# Are lengthy, explanatory answers incentivized?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation

I often hang out in the [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tag where sometimes there's an interesting question I pour lots of time and research into to provide an adequate and lengthy answer. It's really satisfying to me to find I've helped someone out but after I've spent all that time researching, the initial audience of that question has left and the amount of reputation I earn in the long run isn't really proportional to the time I've spent, and as a consequence I sometimes feel reluctant to give lengthy, explanatory answers. Why should I allocate so much time and effort if I could very well just write a code-only answer and get 5 instant upvotes on easier questions? I know I shouldn't care about reputation, but I would like to be rewarded for what I've done.

How do we encourage users to keep on providing quality answers if it's hard to gain reputation (in my experience) and thus drive motivation with these kinds of answers?

Comment: A *weekly / monthly* post on Meta where users - *who pour their hearts out like you want to do* - can share a link and a summary of the "**professional**" answers they've written for **SO** questions that *week / month* - sort of like the "*why you should elect me*" moderator election post. Answers on that Meta post will get voted on thus bringing the best "**professional**"  answers to the top. I think this will trigger the "Meta effect".

Comment: _"the amount of reputation I earn in the long run isn't really proportional"_ -- it has been my experience that reputation earned is barely proportional to _any_ rational metric. Poor questions get up-voted like crazy sometimes. Good answers are ignored. Some tags, even heavily trafficked ones, see only a vote or two per post at the most, while other tags get huge volume of voting input from the community, making reputation across tags not even comparable. IME, you should just ignore reputation. If you don't have other compelling reasons to contribute, don't bother.

Comment: _"Poor questions get up-voted like crazy sometimes"_ -- case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818746/how-to-analyze-a-rectangular-array-and-obtain-the-best-solution-using-maze-back

Comment: FWIW user [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) (who is also a moderator) writes the following on his profile page: [I offer a 500 point bounty for every good canonical you post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254137/871050) - he seems to have followed that through as well :)

Comment: From my experience, I’d say, just keep on writing quality answers. Quality answers can earn you reputation even after several years (which you can’t notice after only 1½ years), which these easy answers won’t. If your answers are good, canonical ones, people will even link to it, raising the likelihood of earning long term reputation. It might be surprising that once you decide to ignore the reputation and keep on writing good answers in your field of interest, the reputation will come by itself…

Comment: strongly related: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: Answers that respect the time of the reader tend to be incentivized.  You can easily do both, a small summary of the answer to start, expound in the rest.  Using rep as an incentive, no, that wears off pretty quickly.  You are at the stage where many SO contributors quit, bored with the grind.  Notable how you got several 500 rep bounties from a chatroom.  Not sure how that happened, I don't want to know.  But that doesn't help either.  If it only matters *who* you know but not *what* you know then they're just dis-respecting your expertise.

Comment: [Good example of one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290599/2441442) 2 years later after the question was asked on a low traffic tag. It's gone crazy on votes. Only give long answers if you think there are possible more people arround there, that could possible benefit from it. Then forget it for a few years and come back later.

Comment: Maybe they [just want an accept](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert.  Eric Lippert has 455404 reputation over 3276 answers, which means he *averages* 139 rep per answer, even after rep caps and "no love for this answer" answers.  His answers are always very detailed and useful.  You can gain a college education in c# just by reading [his most recent posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=answers&sort=newest).

Comment: The majority of my answers are lengthy and explanatory, and since I have plenty of rep, I'd say there are sufficient incentives.

Comment: I made a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/619016/how-well-do-my-lengthy-detail-rich-answers-perform-over-time) and [could not find any meaningful pattern in my own lengthy answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/619016/how-well-do-my-lengthy-detail-rich-answers-perform-over-time?UserId=106224). So, basically what @Peter Duniho said.

Comment: I almost exclusively only add lengthy answers to two types of questions: (1) well established old questions that continue to get a lot of views, and (2) new Q&A style self answers where there isn't another question available. Both of these continue to get upvotes in the long run.

Comment: Isnt part of the reward the satisfaction of learning and being able to write a good answer on a question for which you also gained knowledge? Is the newfound wisdom not part of your reward? Also, maybe codereview would be good for you as they do appreciate the lengthy detailed answers

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Just realized that my average score per answer is just slightly (fractionally!) over 100. I had no idea my answer performance was that close to his. Still, it's worth pointing out that not everyone is Eric Lippert...

Answer (score 35):

This can't come from the system; this has to come from yourself.

Not all answers get a lot of attention, or a lot of praise.  There are even some answers which get a ludicrous amount of praise for seemingly no reason.  There's not really a rhyme or reason to it; it's just how the community reacts to an answer at any given time.

To that, I would say that if you're getting discouraged from writing longer answers - **because you're not getting reputation for it** - perhaps now would be a good time to revisit why you're answering.

I'm not saying that you shouldn't answer questions in long form; quite the opposite.  I genuinely want longer, more detailed answers on the site.  Especially if the question is good and could do with a longer answer than most.  However, I personally wouldn't think of doing this *just* for the reputation involved.

Keep writing the long answers, but do so knowing that you're helping others for the future.  The payoff doesn't need to be immediate, and it's not always immediate for everyone; there are members here (myself included) who get reputation for answers that we wrote *ages* ago, but are still useful to someone who had that question.

If all else fails...take a break from writing the long-form answer.  I wouldn't want you to get too discouraged over this.

Comment: *"However, I personally wouldn't think of doing this just for the reputation involved."* -- yep, agreed. I love helping people out, that's the very reason I'm even contributing on SO, but the side of reputation is nice. I guess I need to concentrate on that less when I answer.

Comment: If anything, I think it's great that we *don't* incentivize long form answers.  That way, when we do get them, they come from people who have done it because they care, and have generally done a very good job.  With incentives come games, and I think we'd end up with a lot more long-form pollution if there were some manner of mystical beast points distributed for their creation.

Comment: But stackoverflow is explicitly designed to measure value by reputation. Of course it's not ever going to be perfect, but I don't think that the right approach to perceived problems with this gamification is to try to ignore them. We should try to figure out how to make the system even better.

Comment: "There are even some answers which get a ludicrous amount of praise for seemingly no reason." Even Mysticial thinks the reception to his branch prediction answer is ridiculously disproportionate. There are many other answers like it; everyone just likes that one because it's famous.

Comment: [People just really like to upvote answers about branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991778/an-expensive-jump-with-gcc-5-4-0/40993519#40993519). That one got hot-network-questioned in a matter of hours, and stayed there for several days. It was actually a good answer, but it received a *highly* unusual response.

Comment: It's most interesting that users with relatively high rep values are commenting that the reputation doesn't matter much. It's like the CEO who's paid $$ and goes on about how much they love their job / product / industry / people, but then take their full share of options as they leave. I don't think there is anything wrong with wanting to be "paid" very well for doing something that you love doing. It's similar to the real-world economy:  Well-paid employees who do poor work don't last long, but that doesn't mean excellent employees who love their job shouldn't get a generous raise.

Comment: @CPerkins: Think of rep like a gold star. More gold stars is better, but the knowledge is more valuable.  If Stack Overflow were to close, you'd still have the knowledge and expertise with you, whereas the virtual points would cease to hold relevance.

Comment: @Makoto I definitely agree that SO as a whole, and individual questions, can have value far beyond the rep and badges, perhaps even making such irrelevant. But my metaphor of real-world jobs and money still holds. One can enjoy life to the fullest just by having work that fulfills the person and brings satisfaction. Some even do cherished work without any monetary compensation, but that hardly diminishes those who also love life and their work but expect and seek after proportional compensation. I don't see a difference with SO unless its intent is to become the monastery of programming. :)

Comment: If anything, at least to some reasonable maximum, more reputation brings with it more privileges, which can enhance and expand a users contribution to the "more valuable" aspects.  I just think the overall sentiment being expressed that the rep doesn't matter so much is a little short sighted, since SO has grown so much with the rep being an integral part.  It could very well be that without the rep and badge system, it would have flopped, or taken long to grow, etc.

Answer (score 7):

A post with 100 upvotes gets a gold badge, and that's more likely to happen with a detailed / explanatory answer that has future value instead of just solving a one-off problem for one asker.

Most of the incentive for writing good explanatory answers is from the satisfaction of doing it right, and writing the kind of answer you'd like to find if you were searching for something.  But badges are one way that the gamification system does incentivize posting fewer good/long answers, rather than many short low-effort answers.

Also the occasional bounty; I've had bounties awarded by askers who really appreciated my detailed explanation of something, even on a question that didn't get much attention.

Getting a gold badge for a great answer is pretty much a lottery, though.  In some tags (like `[x86]` `[assembly]` / performance-optimization where I hang out), it's very rare that a question gets enough traffic to get that many upvotes.  But it's happened a couple times that a good question came along that I was able to write a very detailed answer for, and which caught the attention of the masses.

I have some other canonical answers that are gradually creeping up in rep, and many of them have passed similar short answers with less explanation on similar questions.  So a well-explained answer will keep getting you votes in the long-term, more than you'd get with a mostly-code answer.

---

Definitely the main motivation for me is that SO is a good place to go into massive detail about something specific.  Leaving the info here in answer to a specific question means that people will be more likely to find it in the future than if I wrote blog posts.  (And besides, then I'd need to think of blog-post topics myself instead of waiting for people to ask interesting questions.)

I got my rep the hard way, by tilting at windmills. :P

Recently I've been spending time going back and cleaning up and improving some of my detailed answers, since some of them were written as I was figuring things out.  Also, new CPUs have some differences, so some of my asm optimization answers can use an update.  It's not a lot of fun, but I was burned out on looking at new questions (since by now many of them are the same beginner questions I've seen multiple times before).

I definitely have a hard time keeping my answers from getting unreadably long, though.  Saying a lot with few words is *hard*, though.

> I would have written a shorter letter, but I did not have the time.
>   -- [Blaise Pascal](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal)

Hitting the 30k char limit has forced me to spend time trimming out less-important stuff, or conveying the same info with more brevity.

Comment: or swapping the full Godbolt links for the short ones. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: heh.  But goo.gl links can rot (and godbolt short-links still use that internally).  I've seen a dead shortlink actually happen in one of my answers, unless that was a copy/paste error.  Besides, [using a full-link puts all the information on SO itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319594/224132), so even if godbolt.org dies, another site using the same code could handle the links.  So I try to avoid ever using godbolt shortlinks.

Answer (score 3):

> It's really satisfying to me to find I've helped someone out but after I've spent all that time researching, the initial audience of that question has left

I think the problem comes from a combination of **huge site size and under-use of tag-filtering**. As a consequence, many users probably just check recent questions, spot one that matches their interests, up/down vote the question and a few top answers and/or possibly provide their own answer. Then, unless they get involved in a discussion in the comments, they don't come back to see what's new, because, even if they have time to dedicate to stackoveflow, there are a lot other new questions have been posted meanwhile, and they probably already missed some of those they could have contributed to.

These users will likely never come back to that 6-hours old question for which you have prepared and posted a good quality answer. Your only upvotes will be from people having a problem similar to the OP, where able to find the question, and cared enough to scroll past the upvoted short answers.

If you were on another stackexchange site with much less traffic, things like that would be mitigated. There would be a smaller number of potential up-voters, but each one would be more likely to see your answer.

Comment: As a participant on a much smaller Stack Exchange site [with an answer that seems to fit your parameters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/34275/102), I find myself categorically disagreeing with your assertion.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't blame you for hoarding reputation; why shouldn't you? After all, your motivation for providing answers is entirely up to you. It's being helpful that counts.

Now... getting upvotes on an answer or a question is a two-stage process in my opinion. **Long-term and short-term.**

At first you get what I would call a short-term reward. You often get upvotes for answering the question in a timely manner, to the point and being helpful for the OP. After all the question is new, displayed at the top of tag search queries as well as in the default new/hot tags which being default are the most popular ones.

After the initial novelty of the question wears off you are no longer getting upvotes from the OP and the active community members who are browsing Stack Overflow like crazy. Your upvotes should start coming from newly arrived members who are facing a similar problem as the OP was in the past.

**This is where a lengthy explanatory answers get rewarded.**

People will be more incentivised to link and share your lengthy, explanatory answer wherever they wish, be it on Stack Overflow, their blogs, etc. The chances are that if you provide extra explanation, the answer will be more relevant to other people having a similar problem. This should in theory boost the ranking of your answer in search engines, therefore your answer should get more views => more upvotes.

> Are lengthy, explanatory answers incentivised?

- Short-term?: Not really, besides adding value your main enemy is the time.
- Long-term?: Yes, granted there's a big element of randomness in it. (will the question/answer/tag get popular over time?)

A follow up question pops-up though...

> Should lengthy, explanatory answers be incentivised?

The answer to that should come from some a Stack Exchange mission statement (*[What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)*). Again you see two similar themes (short-term and long-term).

- Short term => being helpful to other programmers facing a similar problem in the simplest manner and shortest time (when was the last time you actually clicked an MSDN forum question/answer?)
- Long term => Building a repository of solutions to common problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as investing.

Maybe the audience size is small, but it could grow later. Most of my rep and gold badges comes from a few early stage answer on Android, back when Android was not popular. So when you answer questions on smaller tags, you take a risk that the question would be unseen vs. it becoming very popular.

And like many investments, around 90% will fail, but the 10% would make up for it. Something hugely popular, like JavaScript, will likely have all the good, easy questions answered, and you'd be lucky to get more than 50 rep for those.

The explanatory answers last for years. However, lengthy might not mean people read it. People here are quite fluent in reading code, perhaps more so than reading documentation, so illustrating something with code can be easier to understand than explaining in English.

In the end, things that people read and understand gets upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is currently phrased, it *may* sound a bit short-sighted at the first glance (!) : Stackoverflow should not be about reputation gains, and "lengthy, explanatory" answers are not necessarily **good** answers. Sometimes, 3 lines of code simply **is** the best answer that you can give.

But it's clear that the core of this question goes beyond that (and that's a point that I've been musing about as well). There are many facets, and the most important ones have already been pointed out in other answers:

- The reputation gain *heavily* depends on the tags that the Q/As fall under
- There is a *significant* difference in the shape of the graph of reputation gain over time.

The second one may be the core of what your question is about. And I think that it is important to differentiate between the short-term and the long-term reputation gains.

---

One thing that may severely distort **short-term** reputation gains: When a question or answer is upvoted several times, it is more likely to appear in the [Moderation Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) (available for >10k users), under one of the sections

> - Questions with extreme votes
> - Answers with extreme votes

This will cause the Q/A to stick out prominently, attracting attention, and causing it to gain more upvotes - this is basically an effect that amplifies itself.

Additionally, a short-lived burst of upvote-clicks may just mean that 100 other people thought: "Yes, that's the trivial answer that I would have written as well". Somehow rewarding, but nothing that lets you stand out.

---

In contrast to that, there is only one thing that may affect the **long-term** reputation gains. Namely, whether the answer is likely to be discovered later, based on a few keywords, and show up as one of the first results of a search engine. This discoverability will of course be amplified when the answer is canonical and many other questions are linking to it.

---

Two extreme examples of short- and long-term reputation gains from my answers:

- The [answer to the question: Is there a limit to the number of nested 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347019/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-nested-for-loops/41348525#41348525) gained >100 upvotes within a week or so. Since then, nobody even noticed it. It's basically "dead".
- The [answer about Using Java with Nvidia GPU's (cuda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda/22868938#22868938) probably counts as "lengthy and explanatory". I wrote it 3 years ago, and now it is one of the top search results when googling for `java gpu`, and I constantly receive a few upvotes per week for it.

The bottom line is: It's up to you to decide which kind of answers you put how much effort in. And although stack overflow is not about reputation per se: Regularly seeing an upvote for an old answer, indicating that someone dedicatedly found this answer helpful, may be far more satisfying than 100 hype-upvote-clicks in one day.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that answering questions has two main benefits:

- You earn reputation
- You learn something while trying to give the most accurate and correct answer

You said that you've done a lot of research while preparing the answer. I assume it was because you weren't sure about some details of the answer, or you just didn't know some things required to give a compelling answer. If I'm correct, then I think you have to ask yourself: "Have I gained enough knowledge **which is interesting to me** while researching to justify for the time spent, taking into consideration that I might get no upvotes (or close to none)?" If yes, then the benefit of the gained knowledge outweighs the fact that you didn't get much reputation points. It will be easier to make that justification when you are answering a question related to a technology in which you're interested in yourself. If you are writing a lengthy answer preceded by tons of research on a topic that you find dull, knowing that you'll probably get close to zero upvotes, I think you shouldn't bother.

Answer (score -1):

> I pour lots of time and research into to provide an adequate and lengthy answer.

So that means, that you get to know things, you did not know/you were not familiar with before, don't you? I do not have nearly the reputation, that you have, but for the answers I provided, I had to do some research. If not, I found myself questioning my beliefs/practices, like in [this answer I provided about assert in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468020/is-assert-false-a-good-practice/36468165#36468165)
So why don't you enjoy learning these things? You won't forget them too soon (I guess).

> It's really satisfying to me to find I've helped someone out[...]

So why don't your write those short answers, if you feel like it? Don't the upvotes show you, that you helped someone? I do not want to discourage you, but I am also someone, that, if I am asking for advice on a specific programming problem, like you should on Stack Overflow, I also like the short answers better - at least most of the time! If I want extended, long post answers, it's most likely to fit into the software engineering forum, so that's the way to go.

> How do we encourage users to keep on providing quality answers [...]

`Quality != length` ! You can write an essay of about 200 pages, if it does not fit the question however, it is still low quality!

Whatever - you have 17k+ reputation. That's quite a lot. So don't be discouraged by not getting many upvotes for every post you do. Do what you like and provide answers, that you think are helping others and the reputation will come by itself. Keep up the good work!