# Is the model still working, or is Stack Overflow outgrowing itself?

Tags: discussion

I was just on the home page, and I think I saw roughly 75% of questions had 0 answers on them. With the flood of questions coming in every day, it is becoming less and less likely each one will get the attention it needs to get answered - and particularly questions that require more than a few lines to get right may not be bothered with.

Has the site's popularity outgrown its format - or rather its default presentation and aggregation?

Comment: old questions have more answers because they have been around longer and had time to accumulate answers, this is not new, it has always been so and yet new users continue to be baffled by this.

Comment: The home page does not list all questions. It also lists new questions first, so you're basically saying that 75% of questions have not been answered within the first 10-20 minutes. That's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas Unanswered questions tend to also fall off the homepage rather quickly, which makes them even less likely to be answered. Again, the list presentation format may not be ideal.

Comment: @WeckarE.: "*which makes them even less likely to be answered*" Untrue. Many people find questions by looking at specific tags, not by the home page.

Comment: The homepage is specifically *designed* to show you unanswered questions.  It exists to show people questions that they can answer, meaning that once a question has gotten a good answer *it's going to fall off the homepage*.  The homepage computes a "score" of each post, and ranks the highest ones.  Having a good answer *lowers* a posts "homepage score".  So you don't see those posts, by design.

Comment: @NicolBolas Those would, I believe, tend to be 'experts', rather than casual answerers, no?

Comment: @WeckarE. I wouldn't expect whether someone uses the homepage versus a tag list to be related to their expertise at all.

Comment: @Servy Casual answerers may not know the tag list option exists. It requires some SE experience before you get there.

Comment: Yes, the site's popularity has outgrown its format but we're not going to change it for another 6 to 8 years.

Comment: @WeckarE. How long they've used the site isn't indicative of their expertise in the topic though.  And it doesn't exactly take much expertise to figure out how the question lists works, that's something people are figuring out early on.  Anyway, how is any of this relevant to your question?

Comment: @RobertLongson Actually in the past questions got more answers more quickly. The cause of this is still a point of debate, however.

Comment: [Yes, it’s getting harder to get an answer on Stackoverflow](https://medium.com/@trieloff/yes-its-getting-harder-to-get-an-answer-on-stackoverflow-3fbe5954d324). Slightly old (Dec 2016) but still relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're describing a double-edged sword here.

*Yes*, there is a flood of new questions coming in and only so many people *willing* in the first place to bother answering them.  This isn't a new problem; not everyone knows every language, and not everyone is asking about Java or C or Swift.

*Yes*, there are questions which require much more than a line or two of explanation - and this is [*generally* a good thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351433/1079354) - but those which are *worth* answering and those which *can* be answered are buried underneath the sheer amount of questions we get *period*.

*Yes*, Stack Overflow is incredibly popular, which is its biggest asset and its biggest weakness.  It's popular, so it's indexed worldwide and the vast majority of programmers come here to solve their problem.  It's popular, so the vast majority of programmers think it's okay to just dump their question on us and ask us to solve it for them.

You're not exactly describing anything new here, and you're not offering much in the way of remedy.  There are pain points everywhere inside of this nuance, but there's no clear indication as to which point hurts more than any other.  You may be right in that the site has outgrown what its presentation format is, but there's no indication that any other presentation format even currently *exists* from anyone else around, nor is it the case that we've truly proven that it's actively harmful to the point of degrading the site.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow's default presentation and aggregation aren't on its own homepage, they're on Google's search results page. Many of the questions you see being ignored are low-quality and/or duplicate questions that will be removed eventually. As long as the majority of programming questions you type into Google find an answer, it's working as intended.