# Why are some truly awful questions staying around for days and days?

Tags: discussion

I was recently going through the [RabbitMQ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rabbitmq), and I was appalled by the nature of many of the questions there. Most of these aren't only Rabbit questions - in fact, the [worst one I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482671/potentially-unhandled-rejection-5-no-endpoints-could-be-reached-warning-non) (see screen clip below) had four tags, some of which are fairly popular.

As most of us know, a good question is far more likely to produce an answer that is useful not only to the OP, but to the community as a whole. Therefore, a systemic quality problem is a community problem. **In this case, the presence of so many low quality questions on this tag makes me loathe to go in and answer any questions on the tag at all.**

1. Why aren't these getting caught in the "low quality" review queue automatically?
2. Is there some reason why a question would only see 10-12 views after being around for a few days? This seems off to me given the massive traffic on this site.

**++Edit**

3. Is it possible to filter out questions with negative votes and/or close votes?

#### Example of Poor Question w/ No Prior Close Votes

[image: Example Bad Question]

Comment: Likely this is because there aren't enough qualified experts to review and clear the queue. This is a perennial problem on this site: too much garbage that's ever increasing, and not enough garbage collectors.

Comment: In this case, the question here wasn't even in the close queue until I down-voted and close-voted. As was the case with 100% of the ones I looked at (if you go look at that tag, all the questions with 1 down vote and 1 close vote are likely because of me). In most cases, I left comments as to what the issue was.

Comment: How many viewers see a question depends on the tags. In small tags, it can happen that there are just a handful of experts.

Comment: I understand that, but node.js and mongo (the question above) are not particularly small tags

Comment: Having the tag helps, but if the title doesn't draw attention it won't... draw attention.

Comment: Less that there aren't enough people to collect garbage, more that their tools are too small, and that actually slowing the flow to make it more manageable has been rejected in favor of "site growth".

Comment: [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=answers&sort=votes#user-tab-answers)

Comment: Less that there aren't enough people to collect garbage, it's that we allow the garbage to enter the system. Prevention is a cheaper use of human time. Not allowing those questions enter the system would solve all problems.

Comment: Small(ish) tags seem especially vulnerable to the weaknesses of SO. (1) I have the only gold badge for one tag but can at most close duplicates (2) I can vote to close poor questions but so few people with high reputations are interested in that tag and active in review that close votes often don't get to 5 (3) very many new questions are from new users who don't understand the purpose or ethos of SO and ask off-topic or unanswerable questions, Net result: frustration.  A critical mass of active, high-rep users is needed for a tag to work well.

Comment: It seems that the good folks at Stack Exchange could address some of these issues, which seem obvious.

Comment: @NickCox By that philosophy, new tags should really be voted in by existing high-rep users to make sure there's a monitoring base.

Comment: @WeckarE. I am positive that my own favourite tag exists, and existed before I joined: otherwise joining and participating in SO would have little point for me. New languages and variants emerge all the time, so there shouldn't be a major threshold to questions being asked on them. My comment is secondary, and little more than that managing smaller tags can be frustrating. I am very ready to believe that there's an opposite picture for more popular tags.

Comment: *"Is there some reason why a question would only see 10-12 views after being around for a few days? This seems off to me given the massive traffic on this site."* - My own experience pool is Java and Node but if I see a question also tagged RabbitMQ, I don't look at it. I simply don't care. So I also wouldn't know to downvote or close vote it.

Comment: @Gimby - do you only ever look at questions with the intent of answering them?

Comment: The low quality posts review queue is there to remove non-answers.  It doesn't evaluate questions.  The close queue would help attract additional close votes once the post gets a few, but it can only do so much.  If such posts do end up getting closed before they're answered, and people don't upvote the questions, they'll be automatically deleted.  If the post attracts answers or upvotes it takes so much attention to actually get it deleted that it generally won't happen (generally speaking, this one example has enough attention from meta to have a shot at getting deleted).

Comment: Yes, this was an easy one. But there are so many that it makes me loathe to go answer RabbitMQ questions, of which I am one of only a handful of people who have significant expertise in that platform.

Comment: The tag is broken beyond fixing.  Atrocious answer rate, nobody earns any rep, not nearly enough hands around anymore to help.  It reached a tipping-point where the network effect broke down.  Users reading each other's answers and learning from them, regardless of the questions.  Until it is all spread too thin and digging through the crap gets to be loathsome, it quickly heads south from there.  It isn't unique to this tag, the smaller ones are dying first.  Only thing you can do is exclaim [it is working as intended!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359692/17034).

Comment: It's just a pity that there doesn't seem to be any effort to remedy the situation. I am an engineer, and I solve problems every day. This does not seem to be that hard of a problem to solve.

Comment: related discussions about improving closing system: [Is using reputation to scale the number of close votes the best way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281818/165773) and [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)

Comment: Honestly, sometimes if I see a duplicate question (Android tag) I will go to the effort of Voting to Close. But often I won't because it is a hassle, and it takes so much to close the question, and then it still keeps hanging around for ages, so it is almost like there is no point. I guess they keep the duplicates around because it is good for business having all the incoming links from Google.

Comment: @theMayer heck no, I only look at questions I have an interest in, one of those interests is a possibility of answering them. Another is wanting to learn something, I do not want to learn anything about rabbitmq. At least not in the context of Node or Java. I think I can read between the lines here: no I don't go looking at questions to see if there is something to fix, vote or flag in them. There is way too much content on this site to take that approach.

Comment: Searching for `score:0` returns only non-negative scoring posts. You can't search for questions with(out) close votes.