# How do I post a comment with a really long URL, which will never fit without a URL shortener?

Tags: discussion, short-links, url-shortener

For example, I am not able to use a URL shortener because it is not allowed, and because of that I am not able to post a comment with this URL:

```
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%3CTType%20extends%20RequestType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20...params%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20sendWorkRequest('foo')%0D%0A%20%20result.split('string')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest()
```

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to post said comment? What's the benefit to the site or the person who posted the question/answer you are commenting on?

Comment: I used a URL shortener earlier today, it worked fine.  I used the google one. Here is the URL in your post shortened using it: https://goo.gl/LMD4Rt

Comment: Note that goo.gl urls would be going down shortly.

Comment: @ChrisF Because they are useful in discussion, for example Dan's comment above.

Comment: Yet another reason why url's should not count towards the character limit unless they are bare.

Comment: Very related: [How are we supposed to post godbolt links now that URL shortening is blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319549/4639281) (that website employs a similar permalinking scheme)

Comment: The goo.gl links seem to work here (http://goo.gl/DKAg9B) but not in non-meta SO comments.

Comment: @trusktr It worked on ELU earlier. Not that specific google-shortened link of course, another one I had call for. Maybe it’s only SO or whatever site you’re using?

Comment: @DanBron Yep, on SO it won't let me.

Comment: @trusktr: "*Because they are useful in discussion*" Comments are not for discussion. If you need to link a user to source code like that, then it should be in the context of a genuine answer, not a comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not necessarily: debating about validity of an answer (and providing support with code samples) can happen in comments. Also "Comments are not for discussion" is ironic. xD

Comment: @Nicol that same discussion was had in the comments under the top answer to the question I linked. It seems the community largely agrees that such links can be useful in comments.

Comment: Suggestion: don't bicker about utility of comments.  Don't bicker about specifics.  Is there **ever**  a valid use for a comment?  I think there is, or the site would not support it.  Is there **ever** a valid use for a URL in a comment?  I think there is, or the site would not support.  So let's posit that we have some situation that merits those.  I claim that one exists, without proof. Now, in that situation, "How do I post a comment with a really long URL, which will never fit without a URL shortener?"  Badgering OP about the specific need in their specific case is kind of silly.

Comment: I guess as a workaround you could use something like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-qv0s6). The TypeScript playground is a bit silly in how it creates perma-links imo