# Why are links URL counted as characters in comments?

Tags: discussion, bug

I work mostly with TypeScript, and we use mostly the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to share live code.

I just had this problem. I commented in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272380/is-there-a-way-to-map-a-function-return-depending-on-the-value-of-a-object-param/58273128#58273128) where I added some implementations and I wanted to share it. The problem is the TypeScript playground link is:

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcnAFzIgCumARtANzmVO0DOYUoAc3aVkCWk3ToANhDghhlACY8+g9gF9SpMAE8ADigzYAKvogAxKFjyRYiFAF5kAeUzAwAHiO58dpABpkAHJFIIA+dlIZMGRIXlpvUwNLa19CCEjQW3TkAGF0EBhgATIRAHd3AAsAEXFJGTkFCm4sCBV+ECEOCnQwSuh2tW7kADc4KXoIbkHOjS1dA2RzehAEMGACgEZkJwAKME3afMLigEodsJJkAG1q5FBkAGsIHXQYPIKigQBdWgYpKTICAAD0gIEU3A+JwEt2+yAA-GhWkkLFZMDYCPZkAlWhi-Ch1JEEAVeBQBBAwM4mAArCBrWjLVbrLY7ZC7YnQo6fM4OS5kYbAd7s7kCAB0FT61XOpRElCgFPoUBAJHUVEhK0eIHQZWVcEh3jx6SayFVECk3BQMtlyHlYEVyuIqr1yA1Wp1aqRJjMKXRaXsxs0mlIHNJmB0xy+XOhrKtyAlNVofEm-mGLWwtCCaYgQRTIl6-SgGfz0BzwzGEymGfLk24paDIZiYaptLWrPJlJpdLAuzDEbO7CbnbWoqAA

What of course breaks the comment character limit. I tried to use a shorter URL so it can be use and I got an error like

> Do not use URL shorteners because they can become invalid. Use the final URL.

So I had to edit my question and put there a comment saying that this code is related to a comment in an answer...

I find this is a bug in the comment system.

Comment: Link URLs contain characters... why would they not be counted?

Comment: [Related 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376124/7296893) (also typescript playground), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked). This is a common issue with an open feature request. Also see the related MSE links on the duplicate.

Comment: Wow, an 2016 issue.

Comment: @distante "Issue" is debatable, I think it's working exactly as it should

Comment: Yeah maybe. Usually when something does not affect us it is not important. But well, I tried.

Comment: Basically you need to use a comment for what it is not intended because you don't really have another place to put that "for further reading" type of link. It's not a bug, more like a lacking feature IMO.