# I cannot post a relevant URL because it is too long, but I cannot post a shortened URL either

Tags: discussion, comments, url-shortener

[image: Comment Post Error]

As suggested, I tried <br><b>replacing</b> the short URL with the URL it redirects to!<br>.

Sadly the short URL redirects to:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature(raw)%5D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Araw%3A%3ATraitObject%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Amem%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Bar%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20for%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(%26self)%20%7B%20println!(%22ok%22)%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20erase%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20%3FSized%3E(r%3A%20%26%27a%20T)%20-%3E%20TraitObject%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute_copy(%26r)%20%7D%20%7D%0Afn%20recover%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20%3FSized%3E(r%3A%20TraitObject)%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20T%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute_copy(%26r)%20%7D%20%7D%20%0A%0Afn%20erase_foo%3C%27a%3E(r%3A%20%26%27a%20Foo)%20-%3E%20TraitObject%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute(r)%20%7D%20%7D%0Afn%20recover_foo%3C%27a%3E(r%3A%20TraitObject)%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20Foo%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute(r)%20%7D%20%7D%20%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20%26Bar%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20erase(r)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20xf%20%3D%20erase_foo(r)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20x.data%2C%20x.vtable)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20xf.data%2C%20xf.vtable)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20recover(x)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20yf%20%3D%20recover_foo(xf)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20y.f()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20yf.f()%3B%0A%7D&version=nightly&backtrace=0

... which does not fit in a comment.

How do we handle situations like this?

Comment: Context: have 100k+ imaginary Internet dollar points, 700+ badgers, ~6.7m imaginary Internet dollar people reached, and 7 Reddit cake days.

Comment: I don't see what exactly we can do about this, though. URL shorteners are horrible and we don't want to allow them, but that also doesn't mean we need to support a website that doesn't know how to use URLs properly and wants to paste the entire block of code you typed into the URL like that. I would suggest using one of the shorter URLs as identified in the answer below.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295084/useful-comment-removed-because-of-bit-ly http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked

Comment: @animuson: You could start by trusting people that have been here for a loooong time and have a lot of reputation. It's kinda ridiculous that I can still get rate-limited by SO chat for posting a few quick messages in a conversation.

Comment: @Xeo: problem is they know there are also people like me who've been around forever, but still can only be trusted with the plastic scissors... :-)

Comment: @Xeo: Even mods get rate-limited for that. And some of our mod tools are rate-limited too... thankfully not deleting things, though.

Comment: You could post that comment as an answer starting with "Assuming you want to use this sort of memory trick," with the code and a link to the example on rust-lang.org. You can always delete the answer if it turns out to not be useful and you are worried about downvotes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton or make it a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: given that mods, effectively, represent a tier of 'most-trusted-users' is that not an argument for removing, or reducing, rate-limits, whether according to rep or role of the user? Especially when the most destructive, though admittedly also possibly the most useful, tool available to you isn't rate-limited?

Comment: @animuson One solution would be to do what Twitter does: treat URLs as a single fixed length (URLs on Twitter are treated as 23 characters no matter how long they are). Another option, if the link is presented with display text (e.g. `[Display this](http://.....)`, is to only count the display text and not the URL.

Comment: @JLRishe: that's what [I and others suggested for Godbolt.org links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked#comment325956_319594), before Matt Godbolt [updated his Javascript to do the goo.gl unwrapping](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319814/224132).  I think SO stores comments in a fixed-size database field, so it would be inconvenient for them to every allow more than 600 chars of actual data, but they should really come up with some kind of escape code or something to allow larger comments for this purpose

Comment: Not all link shorteners are banned. This one (that was the topic of a recent HNQ) still works [http://..ws](http://..ws)

Comment: This bug should be directed at the Rust Lang Play maintainers, not MSO. That URL is absurd.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They have a "Shorten" button which generates a shorter URL that you presumably would not consider absurd. That shorter URL is then blocked by SO. That's what this whole question is about.

Comment: Why people are against such URLs? They have all the state contained within and thus are less suspectible to link rot

Comment: @hvd: Yes, I read the question. There is a middle ground between "URL that requires a terabyte hard drive to store" and "URL shortened off-site by arbitrary third-party service"

Comment: @JLRishe Twitter passes all links through their own t.co link "shortener", then looks up and displays the original in their official UI. But it's not really a shortener at all, just an analytics passthrough which will happily make short links considerably longer, and cannot be opted out of. So, not really something SO should be emulating IMO.

Answer (score 20):

While not ideal, play.rust-lang.org also allows you to link to a GitHub Gist or Playground URL.  Have you considered using either of those?

Playground URL: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02a3ef9987b9c3a8dca1d5283122ef7a&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Gist URL: https://gist.github.com/02a3ef9987b9c3a8dca1d5283122ef7a

Comment: Been there, done that. Pretend the question says "a 1.4kB link" instead of the actual link. This specific link is only there for artistic reasons.

Comment: Artists can be programmers, too. I don't see an issue.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes if you draw a Mona Lisa on the base code of any project I'm working in, either you stop or I do...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Put the 1.4kB link in a Gist or Pastebin paste and link to that. It's an extra click but it seems that would still be the simplest solution in this case.